# how to do this in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I need a table which has two columns:

First column have an ID
Second column have an ID to.

like two person who are friend  then first's ID in first and second's ID in second but

if I need to check the first user's friend then I need to check by two condition

```
check the friend by first column 

check the friend by second column
```

What would be the best way to create this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create table Friends with columns:

```
   UserId   int
   FriendId  int
```

And check does user have friends by just one operation:

```
 SELECT Count(*)
 FROM Friends
 WHERE (UserId = @YourUserId or FriendId = @YourUserId)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid two checks you should always insert rows with the first ID being greater than the second.
That way if you have to check if A and B are friends you will have just one check to do